# Cannot read property of null - react.js state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, setstate

I'm trying to make a todo list app with React and Firebase.

It's a single page app (except for login).
In my Page's component, I call to a List's component.
In my List's component, I get my firebase data that I put in a state.
In React Dev Tool, in my List's component, I can see a state like this :

```
list{items{...},listName:"exemple"}
```

So, in my return, I'm trying to show the listName's value like that: `{this.state.list.listName}`
But I have the following error: : Cannot read property `'listName'` of null

This is my List's component :

```
  class ListPage extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: null,
    };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
    this.listRef = db.ref(`users/${this.props.user.uid}/lists
    ${this.props.cle}`);
    this.listRef.on('value', data=>{
        this.setState({
            list: data.val()
        })
    })
    }
     render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>List : {this.state.list.listName}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Where I am wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because when your component first mounts, the state list is null. Only when the asynchronous firebase response comes back is it loaded with data and becomes non-null. The solution is to check if it's null, so in your `render()` function change this part:

```
<h1>List : {this.state.list.listName}</h1>
```

to this:

```
{ this.state.list && <h1>List : {this.state.list.listName}</h1> }
```

In general it's good to check if objects are defined before accessing their properties. Especially ones you've explicitly defined to be null at some point.

Comment: No worries. Please mark the answer as correct if your issue is solved :)